# How to de-compress old data compressed with addCRYPT?

Tags: compression

since the 2000th years we were using a compression-lib called addCRYPT.dll from a company called littleBIGware for our Windows-apps. Lib and company doesn't exists anymore, but users of our apps created lots of files up to now which are compressed with this lib.

Now for a new version I don't want to use this old lib, but must still be able to decompress the existing data.

I tried Zip, GZip and some others, but with no success.

Does anybody now, how to decompress these data? Here is a hex-dump of the first 64 bytes of some compressed blocks. There is a kind of a pattern visible, but what?

```
015104:  40 9c 00 00 42 5a 68 39 31 41 59 26 53 59 63 98 00 a8 00 30 ba 70 00 7f ff fa 10 8f fb e0 51 7c 77 db ed 7d bb 92 35 77 63 91 75 89 5d 60 65 91 26 b0 bb 32 ed aa 14 b5 a5 35 8d 34 ae dd c6 fa ...
017640:  40 9c 00 00 42 5a 68 39 31 41 59 26 53 59 2d fc 84 c1 00 49 2e 70 00 7f f8 7a 10 ef fb e0 5a ee 3e 9f 1e da ed a5 68 16 d5 ad ad 6b 3d cf 5e a4 f7 6d d6 d3 6b 47 bb ab 76 39 34 d8 ad bd ec ea ...
015760:  40 9c 00 00 42 5a 68 39 31 41 59 26 53 59 a5 a4 8a 00 00 4a 8b f0 00 7f ff fa 14 cf fb e0 51 dd b6 d5 ad 5e d6 fa 9b b9 bb 1a 77 77 6e dd 54 80 52 aa e5 98 cd 6d ad 92 18 bb 7a cb af 53 b1 da ...
015336:  40 9c 00 00 42 5a 68 39 31 41 59 26 53 59 4f 3c 3e 6f 00 2d cd f0 00 7f ff fe 10 8f fb e0 53 9f 6f 66 cb ec f6 6f 64 a2 da da 61 8d 2a 85 6b 4d 04 80 03 2b 1b 20 16 d9 de cf 6a b3 d5 a0 32 52 ...
016240:  40 9c 00 00 42 5a 68 39 31 41 59 26 53 59 af b2 df 80 00 27 bd f0 00 7f fd fa 10 8f fb e0 57 bd 5e 9f 19 f7 67 02 35 b0 dd ba 5d 67 b3 72 ce cd db 7a eb ba ce bd de f6 af 0c d6 ba d7 57 dc 1c ...
```

Comment: Blowfish? The problem is not about decrypting. The data is not crypted, just compressed.

Comment: Have you tried reflector to de-compile the DLL to what it does?  Alternatively you transition away from using the DLL by still having it decompress any files it opens but then re-compress using your preferred compression algorithm/library.

Comment: Its a c-dll, reflector doesn't decompile it. We are going for mobile platforms, so impossible to still use this old windows-dll.

Comment: It is Bzip2 compression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2

Comment: Yes!! Just throw away the first 4 bytes and there is my data. Thanks so much :-)